# Jquery match content and show hide div

Tags: jquery

I'm jquery beginner looking for help. here is my html code.

```html
<div class="swatch_options color">
  <div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="0"> <div class="option_title">color</div>  
  <input id="swatch-0-black-10566137741" type="radio" name="option-0" value="black" checked="">  
  <input id="swatch-0-maroon-10566137741" type="radio" name="option-0" value="maroon"> 
  <input id="swatch-0-green-10566137741" type="radio" name="option-0" value="green"> 
  <input id="swatch-0-blue-10566137741" type="radio" name="option-0" value="blue">
</div>
    
<div class="product_gallery_nav"> 
    <div class="gallery-cell is-nav-selected" data-title="black" style="">
    <img src="black1.jpg" alt="black" ></div>

    <div class="gallery-cell" data-title="black" style="">
    <img src="black2.jpg" alt="black clothing new" ></div> 

    <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="black3.jpg" alt="Slim Lapel Linen Blazer black">
    </div> 

    <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="maroon211.jpg" alt="maroon Linen Blazer ">
    </div> 

    <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="maroon23s2.jpg" alt="Slim  maroon Linen">
    </div> 

     <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="greeen11.jpg" alt="green Blazer ">
    </div> 

    <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="greeen1132.jpg" alt="Slim  green green">
    </div> 

     <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="blue1.jpg" alt="blue Blazer ">
    </div> 

    <div class="gallery-cell">
    <img src="blue2.jpg" alt="Slim  blue green">
    </div> 

</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve.

I wanna hide all "gallery-cell" if gallery-cell image alt content text match with "color" input value match. example - value="black" = alt="black clothing new"

**done** <strike>2nd. show those "gallery-cell" if checked=""</strike>

**done** <strike>3rd. show hide "gallery-cell" div when checked=""</strike>

this is my 1st question if anything wrong then please help me to clean this question.

thank you.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for content but I m totally new for jQuery just know simple jQuery add class , remove class and some simple.

Comment: This isn't a programming school, there are many tutorials on the web.

Comment: yes tried and trying to search to fix my self but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do with jQuery, try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="option-0"]').on('change',function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('img').hide().filter('[alt*="'+val+'"]').show();
  });
});
```

hope this help!

fiddle example: **https://www.bootply.com/qzi0UdlYa3**

Comment: Why put the fiddle on a remote site instead of using a stack snippet here?

Comment: @Barmar it's not like it prohibited to do so, I used to prove my code in bootply and I want this answer short too

Comment: hi thank you for help i fixed most of part now I m try to hide all "gallery-cell" if "color" has more then 1 input but its not working.   

if($('.color').find('input').length > 1){

     $('.gallery-cell').addClass('hide');

}

Comment: try `if ($('.color input').length > 1) $('.gallery-cell').hide();`

Comment: Not prohibited, just less preferable. If you want the answer to be short, you can use the option to hide the snippet by default.

Comment: @Barmar I see, okay, actually I never tried create snippet on SO yet. As I said that I used to prove/test my code in bootply, so instead of copying the script, it's faster to copy the link, that's why.